# how do i scale inflow stream

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, mantaflow

[image: inflow water stream]

i am in the middles of working on my project, in which call for the person to be in the shower, as in bathroon shower, and in working to get the water strean to look like water coing out of a sjower head i can't seem to the the inflow to scale down right, i trie a sphere, plance,cone, and so far a cylinder i as close as i can get, my question is how do i scale it down from bif ( as seen in the picture) down to a small stream ? i know resolution plays a part in this picture i have the reolsution set low(32) because i know the smaller the resolution it becomes more difficult to reduce. what do i have to to get it smaller?
any help or advice is appreciated and i can send the . blend file, as this is a inflow set-up